# enable function at timer stop c#

Tags: c#, timer

I guess this question has been asked like a 1000 times but I don´t know what I`m doing wrong. I use a timer in C#. If it expires, a value should be set to 1 in order to enable an other function. My intention is to block a function till the timer ticks. If the timer stops, the new function should be enable.

```
using System.Timers;    
public float testNumber;
private Timer timer;


void Gearup ()
{

    if (currentGear < 5) {
        currentGear = currentGear + 1;

        timer = new Timer ();
        timer.Interval=2000;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Start();
        testNumber = 10;
    }
    if (timer.Enabled != false) {
        testNumber = 1;

}
```

Could you guys help me ? Every time I test my code, test number is immediately set to 1. Please be gentle, I know that I
am a noob.

update Question: My problem is, that my game character should shift a gear in the game. Once the gear is shifted, the character shouldnt be allowed to shift it right back. Thats why i want to block the shift function for a coupe of seconds.

Comment: Please show us the entire method. Include the line that declares the timer variable.

Comment: I truly do not understand what you are trying to achieve. Please, can you edit the question and clarify your purpose? There is a chance that a `Timer` is not what you really want.

Comment: @TotalNoob do not post a comment with a lot of lines of code. You can easily [edit] your question and format your code appropriately

Comment: @Steve I´m sorry, i changed it

Answer (score 1):

So you need to start a timer with an interval of two seconds. When the timer elapses you want to set the variable *testNumber* to one.
This happens just one time then stops.

Then you should set the AutoReset property to false and add an event handler for the Elapsed event

```
testNumber = 10;
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Elapsed += (s, o) => 
{ 
     Console.WriteLine("Timer elapsed"); 
     testNumber = 1;
};
timer.Interval = 2000;
timer.AutoReset = false;
timer.Start();
```

Now you don't need to stop and check anything. Continue with your code exiting from the Gearup method. The global variable testNumber will be set to 1 after the Interval period elapses.

Answer (score 0):

When your timer starts `timer.Enabled` is set to true. And then your programm jumps in the

```
if (timer.Enabled != false) {
        testNumber = 1;

}
```

block. Because timer.Enabled is **not equal** false it's **true**! You have to cahnge it to

```
if (timer.Enabled == false) {
        testNumber = 1;

//for timer restart use:
timer.Start();

}
```

or

```
if (timer.Enabled != true) {
            testNumber = 1;
//for timer restart use:
timer.Start();

}
```

Comment: But Enabled = False will be only after 2 seconds. The if will be evaluated a lot of time before the timer triggers the first event, And in any case Autoreset = True means that it will never be Enabled = False.

Comment: @Steve you could restart the timer in the if block.